# How to retrieve apache nutch crawled data to my web

Tags: api, solr, nutch

I am new to apache nutch. I have crawled two website data by apache nutch to solr and executed query and get that in json form. I do I show those crawled data my website. I have just started exploring apache nutch & solr. It is very important for my project. Please suggest some tutorial if availble. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use php then Solarium is a good start [see here](https://github.com/solariumphp/solarium)

You could also try [Solr PHP Client](https://github.com/PTCInc/solr-php-client) there you have to code more.

From the Solr PHP Client you can search in your Solr collection(core) and get the data out in JSON and other formats.

Hope that this helps

Answer (score 0):

In the long run you are better off using Elasticsearch. More powerful and flexible and even a bit faster I believe than Solr.